# Redux-form is not receiving onChange automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have created a component as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ToggleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup';

import { noop } from '../../utils';

const ButtonGroup = ({ options, value, onChange }) => {
  console.log(onChange, 'onChange');
  console.log(value, 'value');
  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      value={value}
      exclusive
      onChange={(event, val) => { onChange(val); }}
    >
      {
        options.map(option => (
          <ToggleButton value={option}>
            {option}
          </ToggleButton>
        ))
      }
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
};

ButtonGroup.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

ButtonGroup.defaultProps = {
  options: [],
  onChange: noop,
  value: '',
};

export default ButtonGroup;
```

I am trying to use it as follows:

```
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onCreateElement)}>
    <label htmlFor="element-type">Select an option</label>
    <div className="selectable">
      <Field
        name="element-type"
        className="form-field"
        component={ButtonGroup}
        options={['One', 'Two', 'Three']}
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </Form>
```

But redux-form is never passing its onChange method to my component. So, my component does not change the selected value.

Here is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yw7xj3vvx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! god, it was a very small mistake taken as big mistake by me. I need to use `props.input.value` and `props.input.onChange` inside the componet. So, my newer code should look like:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ToggleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButtonGroup';

import { noop } from '../../utils';

const ButtonGroup = ({ options, input }) => {
  return (
    <ToggleButtonGroup
      value={input.value}
      exclusive
      onChange={(event, val) => { input.onChange(val); }}
    >
      {
        options.map(option => (
          <ToggleButton value={option}>
            {option}
          </ToggleButton>
        ))
      }
    </ToggleButtonGroup>
  );
};

ButtonGroup.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  input: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
};

ButtonGroup.defaultProps = {
  options: [],
  input: {},
};

export default ButtonGroup;
```

Usage should remain the same.